# using task worker in javaFX to do background task always

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have a background thread in javafx that according to some objects fields change return another object and I should update UI according to this new object .
and I need to repeat this always . but unfortunately it repeats just one time!
I don't understand why .
I mean that output is : "id" (just one time!)

```
 Task<Category> n = new Task<Category>() {

        @Override
        protected Category call() throws Exception {
            final int catNum = iterateAllCat.size();


            while (true) {
                 boolean catDone = false;
                System.err.println("id");

                for (int i = catNum - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    final Category cat = iterateAllCat.get(i);
                        if (cat.done) {
                            break;
                        }
                        catDone = true;

                    if (catDone) {
                        System.err.println("done");
                        break;
                    }
                }
                return category;
            }
        }

    };
    n.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Category>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Category> observable, Category oldValue, Category newValue
        ) {
            try {
                board.categoryPane(++num);
            } catch (NullPointerException n) {

            }
        }

    }
    );




    Thread t = new Thread(n);
    t.setDaemon(true);
    t.start();
```

Comment: Can you fix your code? The `{ }` don't match.

Comment: You execute a `return` statement at the end of the first iteration of your `while` loop. That will exit the method, thereby terminating the task.

Comment: How can I fix it? I should to repeat it always and return category object too!

Comment: You can try calling `updateValue(category);` instead of the return, and then putting a return statement outside the loop. To be honest, though, what you are doing makes no sense at all to me.

Comment: Thank's....But Why make no sense?! :) I just need to check something in scene graph always(It is changing by user... and according to it change something else !

Comment: Why not just register listeners with the properties that might change? At the very minimum, if this is a result of a user action, then you already have "hooks" for code to execute via event listeners. And then, your code makes no sense at all. You set `catDone = true` and then immediately do `if (catDone) { break;}`, so your `for` loop can only possibly iterate once.

Comment: it is more complex to use listener....and I deleted some parts of logic to become short!

Comment: More complex than code that doesn't work?

Comment: honestly don't know...I will try it agin :)